# SQLAlchemy: how to create dynamic columns multiple times

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-metadata

I succeeded to create a sql table with columns defined dynamically, thanks to python class reflexion. 
But I cannot run the code more than one time. 
For instance, the following *import_file* , should create a static table and a dynamic table with specific columns.
It works if I run it one time. But the second time it crashs and returns the following error :

```
Table 'dynamic' is already defined for this MetaData instance
```

Code example :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean, Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import clear_mappers

import os

def import_file(filename, columns):
    path =  filename
    if os.path.exists(path):
        os.remove(path)

    engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{path}", echo=True)

    clear_mappers()
    Base = declarative_base()

    class StaticTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = "static"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)


    class DynamicTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = "dynamic"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    for c in columns:
        setattr(DynamicTable,c,Column(String))

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


import_file("test.db", columns = ["age","test"]) # WORKS
import_file("test2.db", columns= ["id","age","foo","bar"]) # NOT WORKING
```

I try to use **sqlalchemy.orm.clear_mappers**, but unsucessfully.
Any idea how can I resolve it ?

Comment: SQLAlchemy does not allow you to define a model for a database table twice. You are redefining the models on every call of your function.

Comment: So, suppose I would like to create many sqlite file with different tables shemas and same name.  How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not full you code, because conflicts on **Base.metadata**

Mappers for **link** on orm classes and tables, you have defined tables.

You can try somethink like that

```
import_file("test.db", columns = ["age","test"])
Base.metadata.clear()
sqlalchemy.orm.clear_mappers()
import_file("test2.db", columns= ["id","age","foo","bar"])
```